# What type of user information provided by OpenID from google and yahoo

Tags: asp.net, openid, dotnetopenauth, google-openid

I am using openId on website and want to login through yahoo or Google account but it retrieves only 
email or username other fields are null. I have seen lots of blogs links but still not getting solution..!